# Finding Object Reference

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

I wanted to pick a reference of a class Reference which holds the value of a string refer = "yes",  from given references.

The result should be r1. 
How can I achieve this ?

```
public class Reference {

    String refer = "";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Reference r1 = new Reference();
        r1.refer = "yes";

        Reference r2 = new Reference();
        r2.refer = "No";
    }
}
```

Comment: cant understand what you need...

Comment: `if(YourReference.refer.equals("yes"){return YourReference}`

Comment: @Sybren Don't use `==` to compare content of strings.

Comment: if you create Reference array then you can check  through a loop

Comment: _pick a reference of a ... Reference ..., from given references._ What?

Comment: Can there be more than Reference objects where refer field is yes. If so what output would you want?

Comment: Thanks for the response. There can be more objects but with different string values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `equals()` method of `String` to compare Strings.

like, `if(r1.getRefer().equals("yes"))`

for betterment you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` function since it is case insensitive.

If you want reference of the object which satisfies this condition then just assign `r1` to some object after the if condition.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for, as silly as the request may seem.

Comment: If he want to find it among a collection of objects then obviously he should use Collections. or atleast an array of Reference objects

Comment: Thanks for the response. My actual goal is to find an object based on its value if it does not exists I should create one. ideally there should be number of objects.